# What is the probability that the bridge will be empty.

Tags: probability

It takes 5 minutes to cross a certain bridge. It is computed that 1000 people cross it in a day of 12 hours (in other words if we consider every 12 hours period in a day, 1000 people will cross the bridge), the density of people on bridge is equally likely at each time in a day.

Find the probability that there will be nobody on the bridge at noon ?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  It is clear that you will have to make some assumptions about the probability distribution.  After all, if everybody crosses between $9:00$ and $10:00$ then the answer is $0$, while if everyone crosses exactly at noon, the answer is $1$.  What assumption(s) seem appropriate to you?

Comment: But if everybody cross the bridge between 9:00 and 10:00, then the assumption "every 12 hours period in a day, 1000 people will cross the bridge" will not be true.

Comment: That assumption has to be probabilistic, not literal.  You need to assume some probability distribution that has the property that the average over any $12$ hour period is $1000$.

Comment: Just to say:  the answer is pretty clearly $0$, under any sensible assumption.  There are $144$ five minute intervals in any twelve hour stretch, so we have to imagine that an average of $\frac {1000}{144}=6.9\overline 4$ people cross in any five minute interval, which makes $0$ look extremely unlikely.

Comment: I believe this is more an application of pigeonhole principle than probability.

Comment: This was just asked sometime back, possibly deleted and posted again.

Comment: @lulu: extremely unlikely, yes. But not zero -- see my answer.

Comment: @TonyK.  Sure, I was just making the broader claim that $\textit {any}$ sensible assumption about the probability would give an answer which was effectively $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For concreteness, I assume the following setup:

We have $1000$ people, each of whom has to cross the bridge within a certain $12$-hour period. Each of them independently chooses a starting time uniformly from $6$:$00$ am to $5$:$55$ pm.

Then for each person, the probability that they are on the bridge at noon is simply $11$ hours $55$ minutes divided by $5$ minutes, i.e. $1/143$. So the probability that nobody is on the bridge at noon is
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{143}\right)^{1000}\approx 0.000896$$

Note that my assumption is not consistent with your statement that the density of people on the bridge is equally likely throughout the day: it will tail off at the end, because nobody starts the crossing in the last five minutes. If we adjust for this by assuming that people are allowed onto the bridge until $6$:$00$ pm, then we get instead
$$\left(1-\frac{1}{144}\right)^{1000}\approx 0.000941$$

Answer (score 2):

I would have thought the natural assumption to make was that the process was [Poisson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Assuming that, we see that the mean in any $5$ minute period must be $\lambda=\frac {1000}{144}=6.9\overline 4$ so the result would be $$\frac{\lambda^0 e^{-\lambda}}{0!}=e^{-6.9\overline 4}=.00096398$$

Of course other assumptions are possible, but the mean over the five minute period is so high that all answers should give an answer near $0$.

Answer (score -1):

Since it takes five minutes to cross the bridge, for the probability to be greater than 0, we have a max limit of $\frac{12 \times 60}{5} = 144$ people. If the number of people is less than 144, then the probability would be greater than 0. Since this is not the case, the probability is $0$.

Comment: We must assume that people arrive at random times throughout the day, and that the bridge can accommodate more than one person at a time. The probability that nobody is on the bridge at noon is certainly very low, but it is not zero.

Comment: _the density of people on bridge is equally likely at each time in a day_: this should be clarified by the author but since the density is equally likely, I have also assumed the same

Comment: Yes. But your answer is still wrong.

Comment: You are implicitly assuming a constant rate of traffic across the bridge, that is you are assuming a deterministic process, with no probability.  That is, at least, unlikely to be desired assumption here.